# C# Selection Change index out of range

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

When I select the item the grid work perfectly but... when I press the left button to select a other exercise the application crash.

This is the code:

```
int specialbtnId = 0;

private void gvSpecialPagesViewExercise_SelectionChanged(object sender,
    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (specialbtnId)
    {
        case 0:
            LoadSpecialPagesBookExcersices(lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices
                .ElementAt(gvSpecialPagesViewExercise.SelectedIndex));
            break;
        case 1:
            LoadSpecialPagesBookExcersices(lstCurrentPageLeftButton2Excersices
                .ElementAt(gvSpecialPagesViewExercise.SelectedIndex));
            break;
        case 2:
            LoadSpecialPagesBookExcersices(lstCurrentPageLeftButton3Excersices
                .ElementAt(gvSpecialPagesViewExercise.SelectedIndex));
            break;
        case 3:
            LoadSpecialPagesBookExcersices(lstCurrentPageLeftButton4Excersices
                .ElementAt(gvSpecialPagesViewExercise.SelectedIndex));
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the other vent button, is the only codes Im using right now to change the exercise and parts of the exercise.

```
private void UpdateLeftButtonContent()
    {
        ResetSpecialPagesButtonColors();
        if (currentPageSettings.PageStyle.Contains("Especiales"))
        {
            if (lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices != null)
                lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices.Clear();
            if (lstCurrentPageLeftButton2Excersices != null)
                lstCurrentPageLeftButton2Excersices.Clear();
            if (lstCurrentPageLeftButton3Excersices != null)
                lstCurrentPageLeftButton3Excersices.Clear();
            if (lstCurrentPageLeftButton4Excersices != null)
                lstCurrentPageLeftButton4Excersices.Clear();
            foreach (BookExercises x in lstCurrentPageBookExercises)
            {
                if (x.AssignmentCode == 0 && x.Id == 0)
                {
                    lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices.Add(x);
                }
                if (x.AssignmentCode == 0 && x.Id == 1)
                {
                    lstCurrentPageLeftButton2Excersices.Add(x);
                }
                if (x.AssignmentCode == 0 && x.Id == 2)
                {
                    lstCurrentPageLeftButton3Excersices.Add(x);
                }
                if (x.AssignmentCode == 0 && x.Id == 3)
                {
                    lstCurrentPageLeftButton4Excersices.Add(x);
                }
            }
            if (lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices.Count > 0)
            {
                btn1SpecialPages.DataContext = lstCurrentPageLeftButton1Excersices.ElementAt(0);
            }
            if (lstCurrentPageLeftButton2Excersices.Count > 0)
            {
                btn2SpecialPages.DataContext = lstCurrentPageLeftButton2Excersices.ElementAt(0);
                btn2SpecialPages.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btn2Line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            }
            else
            {
                btn2SpecialPages.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btn3SpecialPages.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btn4SpecialPages.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btn2Line.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btn3line.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btn4line.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            }
            if (lstCurrentPageLeftButton3Excersices.Count > 0)
            {
                btn3SpecialPages.DataContext = lstCurrentPageLeftButton3Excersices.ElementAt(0);
                btn3SpecialPages.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btn3line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                btn3SpecialPages.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btn4SpecialPages.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btn3line.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btn4line.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            if (lstCurrentPageLeftButton4Excersices.Count > 0)
            {
                btn4SpecialPages.DataContext = lstCurrentPageLeftButton4Excersices.ElementAt(0);
                btn4SpecialPages.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btn4line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                btn4SpecialPages.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                btn4line.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }


            GridSectionTitle.DataContext = null;
            GridSectionTitle.DataContext = currentPageSettings;
        }


    }
```

Comment: could you please show the `ButtonClick` event handler code also?

Comment: handle exception and show what is the error message.

Comment: You could simplify your code by inserting your lists into an array `List<Exercise>[] exercises = new List<Exercise>[4];` `exercises[0] = new List<Exercise>();`

Comment: @ItiTyagi The error message trow me is this:  Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Debug, debug, debug! Set a breakpoint, step through your code and inspect the variables!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no item is selected, `gvSpecialPagesViewExercise.SelectedIndex` will be -1 which is an invalid value for `ElementAt`.

Add a handler before the switch to prevent that exception:

```
if(gvSpecialPagesViewExercise.SelectedIndex <= 0)
   return;
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly trow me -1.

Answer (score 0):

While not answering your question (apparently you found the bug meanwhile), here are a few tips:

Your code looks very complicated because you are handling the four lists individually. If you put them in an array, you can handle them globally and thus simplify your code.

```
List<BookExercises>[] exercises = new List<BookExercises>[4];

private void UpdateLeftButtonContent()
{
    ResetSpecialPagesButtonColors();
    if (currentPageSettings.PageStyle.Contains("Especiales")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < exercises.Length; i++) {
            exercises[i] = new List<BookExercises>();
        }
        foreach (BookExercises x in lstCurrentPageBookExercises) {
            if (x.AssignmentCode == 0 && x.Id >= 0 && x.Id < exercises.Length) {
                exercises[x.Id].Add(x);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

---

```
int specialbtnId = 0;
private void gvSpecialPagesViewExercise_SelectionChanged(object sender,
    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{  
    // If you are sure that this condition is always true, you can drop it.
    if (specialbtnId >= 0 && specialbtnId < exercises.Length) {
        BookExercises lst = exercises[specialbtnId];
        int index = gvSpecialPagesViewExercise.SelectedIndex;
        if (index >= 0 && index < lst.Count) {
            LoadSpecialPagesBookExcersices(lst[index]);
        }
    }
}
```